# C++ and Qt or Java?

Tags: java, c++, qt, qt4, voip

I was wondering which was more preferable for a VoIP Application that runs on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux. Java or C++ and Qt?
I know Java runs inside the JVM and is limited due to that which means it can't communicate with the hardware directly which might be a downfall. But in your opinion which seems for plausible to use for such an application. ( eg. Jitsi using java or Skype with Qt )

Answer (score 1):

Both are capable languages that are widely used for commercial application development. neither Java nor C++ is inherently a more suitable language for the sort of application you've described.

I personally prefer Qt for application development because I am more comfortable with C++ and in my experience, it is easier to develop attractive applications using Qt and C++ than it is to do the same using Java and Swing, SWT, AWT, or GWT.

Comment: I also wanted to know if Java could look as good as something made using Qt

Comment: @user2578784 I've given you my personal opinion :).